Can someone advice me how to convert or upgrade an old openlayers OSM map code?
I set up a  couple of web sites several years ago that visualize survey data on clickable maps. Example:

I put a lot of effort into coding at the time and have not developed the sites further since they have continued to "do the job".  The code in the simplest form was:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<title>OpenLayers Simplest Example</title>
<div id="demoMap" style="height:250px"></div>
<script src="ol/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    map = new OpenLayers.Map("demoMap");
    map.addLayer(new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM());
    map.zoomToMaxExtent();
</script>

and I have had the css- and js-files in the ol folder on the web server. After this summer all maps are down, with the errors:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED polyfill.min.js:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ';'
Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined at onload

The lines at the "unexpected token" look like this:
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result_poi)) {
        $rows[] = $row;
}

The error message "init is not defined" signals that the the old and basic ol code no longer works. That code looks like this:
    function init() {
        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ],
            controls: ol.control.defaults({
                zoom: true,
                attribution: false,
                rotate: true
            })
        });

I understand that polyfill is a compromised link and have removed it. I also understand there have been new openlayer versions since I developed my web sites, and I am certain the new versions are much better than the old one. However, the old one was very sufficient, and whilst trying to upgrade to the new version I am not even managing to get the "Simple Map" to work. I have downloaded the v10.0.0-package and unzipped the files into the ol-folder on the host, but this does not seem to work (it complains about "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "rbush". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"). I changed all of the links in the main.js file so they pointed to the correct path, but I cannot find rbush anywhere. The quick start seems to tell me how to setup a local server with openlayers, but I'm using a host server and cannot install or configure the host.
I would really like to either get my existing code to keep working, OR adjust it to the new openlayer version. But I just don't seem to understand the new way of using openlayers. Are my web maps lost for ever, or does someone have a solution that does not require me to relearn and recode everything? I would really appreciate some advice before messing up something that could work with minor adjustments.

It would be helpful if you edit you post and add a tag for the coding language(s). The language is more important in terms of getting the right people looking at your post than tags like upgrade or installation

Thanks for suggestions! It turned out I had a mysqli connection that suddenly needed to be set with charset utf8. Non utf8 characters created a problem in the code when json_encode  tried to create an array, and the resulting array became empty. thus, not openlayers fault, but bad diagnostics from my part.

Although there have been some changes since version 4 a good starting point is the version 4 examples https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/simple.html
In version 10 the map div must have sized, and ol.control.defaults becomes ol.control.defaults.defaults


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v10.0.0/ol.css">
    <style>
      .map {
        width: 100%;
        height: 250px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v10.0.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script>
      const map = new ol.Map({
          target: 'map',
          layers: [
            new ol.layer.Tile({
              source: new ol.source.OSM(),
            }),
          ],
          controls: ol.control.defaults.defaults({
            zoom: true,
            attribution: false,
            rotate: true,
          }),
          view: new ol.View({
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2,
          }),
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>



If possible download the ol.css and ol.js onto your server.

Thanks for the help. By letting me confirm server functionality with this simple code I managed to find the actual problem, which was encoding from mysql to json. Saved me a lot of headache!
